# conditional replacement in a file based on a column

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file with several columns that looks like this:

```
MARKER      EA  NEA N_x        EA_y NEA_y N_y
rs1000000   G   A   231410.0    G   A     118230.0
rs10000010  T   C   322079.0    C   T     118230.0
rs10000017  C   T   233146.0    C   T     118230.0
rs10000023  G   T   233860.0    T   G     118230.0
rs10000027  C   G   72852.4     C   G     118230.0
rs10000029  T   C   179950.0    NA  NA    NA    
rs1000002   C   T   233932.0    C   T     118230.0
```

I want to replace values in columns EA and NEA with values from EA_y and NEA_y, but if EA_y and NEA_y are NA then I want to keep values in EA and NEA. 
I can do it in R but using `ifelse` but I would like to learn how to do it with `awk` or similar.
Note: the file has approximately 3 million rows

Comment: There is nothing to replace in your example all the columns are always the same except for the NA row. Could you write a better sample file.

Comment: I have changed the file, now there are some different values

Comment: When the 5th field is set to "NA", are always the 6th and 7th fields always set to "NA" too?

Comment: Yes, they are always "NA"

Comment: In this case you can speed up the awk command testing only one field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk you can do this easily:

```
awk '$5 != "NA" && $6 != "NA" {$2=$5; $3=$6} 1' file | column -t

MARKER      EA_y  NEA_y  N_x       EA_y  NEA_y  N_y
rs1000000   G     A      231410.0  G     A      118230.0
rs10000010  T     C      322079.0  T     C      118230.0
rs10000017  C     T      233146.0  C     T      118230.0
rs10000023  G     T      233860.0  G     T      118230.0
rs10000027  C     G      72852.4   C     G      118230.0
rs10000029  T     C      179950.0  NA    NA     NA
rs1000002   C     T      233932.0  C     T      118230.0
```

I used `column -t` for tabular formatting of output.

Comment: Thanks a lot @anubhava

Comment: I have tried to put your solution in a for loop to apply a several files but it doesn't work, could you check the syntax: `for file in $(ls -1 *_mergedUKBB.txt); do awk -OFS="\t" '$5 !="NA" && $6 !="NA" {$2=$5; $3=$6} 1' "$file" > "$file".tmp; done`. Thanks

Comment: `ls` is unnecessary in `for` loop but can you tell what is not woking? Do all the files contain same # of columns?

Comment: yep, it contains the same number of columns. The problem is if I add `OFS` the replacement is not made. When I remove the `OFS` parameter it works

Comment: Ah it should be: `file in *_mergedUKBB.txt; do awk -v OFS="\t" '$5 !="NA" && $6 !="NA" {$2=$5; $3=$6} 1' "$file" > "$file".tmp; done` (note use of `-v` before `OFS=..`

Answer (score 0):

Since fields 5, 6, 7 are always set to "NA" at the same time, you can use:

```
awk -v OFS="\t" 'NR>1&&$7!="NA"{$2=$5;$3=$6}1' file
```

If you want to proceed several files, avoid to use a loop on the output of the `ls` command, it's better to use `find` that gives you more control on how the path looks like.